# Does GeoServer has CVE-2022-42889 vulnerability?

Tags: geoserver

I'm looking to see if Geoserver (version 2.19 or later) has [CVE-2022-42889](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-42889) vulnerability. I tried to check it, but could not find any reference of having this vulnerability. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoServer and the GeoTools library it is built with are open source projects so you can inspect the code yourself to see if they are impacted by a CVE. However, to save you time in this case I can say that as far as the developers are aware GeoServer and GeoTools are unaffected by this CVE. However a [pull request](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/4048) to upgrade the apache text library to the latest version has been applied so this will be available in all builds made since the 14th October.

Comment: Thanks Ian for your quick response. Much appreciated!

Comment: -please upvote and or accept the answer if it helped you